# Can you add the same custom control to an xpage multiple times

Tags: xpages

I've created a cc that creates a google chart - I pass data to it via compositeData

Can I add more than one to an xpage?

Comment: Have you tried? :-)

Comment: yeah only one is showing! Wondering if this is expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong/stupid :)

Comment: OK - So I've managed to add 2 "Hello world" ccs - must be something more to do with the cc

Comment: I suppose your issue with two or more charts is that some variables have the same global name in client-side JavaScript?

Comment: Yes - that is probably the reason